# Javascript Regexp to find the combination of < and > in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a input text field where need to restrict user to enter combination of < and >.
RegExp Used:

```
var reg = /<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i;
```

Combinations which is not covering:

```
<>
</div>
<121343#>
<@34>
<!@#$<>?"|>
```

I need regexp that validate text string with which has any character/number/special character in-between or before or end with the combination of `<>`.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Use a `^<[\s\S]*>$` pattern.

Comment: how about `<<<<>` or `<><><>`?

Comment: @georg, yup working fine on that. Failing on <<<>><<

Comment: the question was if these are acceptable

Comment: No it shouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<[\s\S]*>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WmxIu7/2) (where `[\s\S]` is replaced with `.*` in order to stay on the same line).

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `[\s\S]*` - any text, zero or more chars
- `>` - a `>` char.

Comment: It is failing for this string <>dsfsf

Comment: @Indhu Right, do you want to match `<...>` anywhere inside the string? Then remove `^` and `$`.

Comment: Yes, I removed it and it was working perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option in JavaScript is using `[^]` to match [any char](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) including newlines.

```
<[^]*>
```

Or not crossing newlines

```
<[^\r\n]*>
```